# Call an async method in the immediate window Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, async-await, immediate-window

I'm stopped in a breaking point and I need to watch the result of calling, in this context, an async function using the Immediate Window. So I tried

```
var things = await Client.GetThingsAsync("aParameter");
```

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider
>   marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return
>   type to 'Task'.

But the breakpoint is already inside an async method. Also I've tried to run

```
var things = Client.GetThingsAsync("aParameter");
```

> "Evaluation requires a thread to run temporarily. Use the Watch window
>   to perform the evaluation."

So I tried the Watch window with

```
ClientGetThingsAsync("aParameter").Result;
```

> "The function evaluation requires all threads to run."

Editing the code and rebuilding is breaking me as it takes to build 15 minutes each time. What strategies are available to call async calls while debugging?

Answer (score 16):

You'll need to do things manually – without `await`.

```
var things = ClientGetThingsAsync("aParameter").Result;
```

As the compiler notes, you need an `async` function in which to use `await`, but you don't control the function when using the immediate window.

Comment: "Evaluation requires a thread to run temporarily. Use the Watch window to perform the evaluation."

Comment: The watch windows (you can have up to four open: look in the Debug | Windows menu while debugging) allow you to watch arbitrary expressions

Comment: I use ClientGetThingsAsync("aParameter").Result; and I get "The function evaluation requires all threads to run."

Comment: @user33276346 I have seen that, using F5 to run until the next breakpoint will sometimes help. Otherwise debug in your main application code (rather than in the debugger) even if throw away code.

Comment: I did this in VS 2019 (16.11.5) in a ASP.NET Core 3.1 project and it made VS completely freeze and lock-up for 5 minutes before I killed it - wow.

Answer (score 13):

In the watch window, click on the little icon on the right side of the message.
[image]